# How do I optimize the amount of XP I can get in a playthrough?

Tags: call-of-juarez-gunslinger

I would like to get the optimum amount of experience points in my playthrough. What I initially noticed is that there seems to be an XP bonus or multiplier if I kill an enemy by headshot.

Please share tips or strategies on getting the optimal amount of XP in a playthrough (skill choices, order of getting skill choices, best ways to kill enemies, etc). Will choosing one of the skill trees first favor optimal XP collection?